# Do local notifications in iOS require a developer account?

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I've discovered that Push notifications require me to first have a developer account in order to activate them in xCode. Is this also true for local notifications?

Thanks!

Comment: __tl;dr__ nope.

Comment: @Simon,  I am using work manager for background process in flutter which hit the api and once I get response I am showing local notification, I am not using any Firebase FCM Service , so do I need to Choose Push Notification Service while creating identifiers and do I need to use APN SSL certification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to test local or push notification in device, you will need to create certificates and profiles which do require developer account.

If you want to test local notification in simulator, then you won’t need developer account. Push notification cannot be tested in simulator, so you will need to have developer account in order to test in device.

Comment: So, what your saying is that I will need a developer account for local notifications if I want to, as an example, distribute the app to testers?

Comment: Local notification can be tested in simulator so you will not need a developer account, however, if anything needs to be tested in device, an apple developer account will be required to generate required certificates and profiles.

Comment: Okay! What about building directly to a USB-connected device via xCode?

Comment: Anything you want to test in device will require certificates and profiles which can be generated from an apple developer account.

Answer (score 1):

Local notifications do not require anything.

However push notifications do require.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Mohammad,  I am using work manager for background process in flutter which hit the api and once I get response I am showing local notification, I am not using any Firebase Service, so do I need to Choose Push Notification Service while creating identifiers , and do I need to use APN SSL certification?

Comment: no, in your case no need. but this is only possible in the foreground right?

Comment: Thanks for the faster response Mohammad, can I know if there any way to run background process every minute in Flutter, seems Work Manager only supports Min 15 minutes for dispatching event

Answer (score 0):

No local notifications doesn't require an apple developer account. As it doesn't makes sense also because no where you will be connecting with APNs or you will be requiring any token or any other thing

Any app if you want to be in **device** whether it's configured with local notification or not you want a developer account.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got the opposite answer from Hooda though. Hooda claims that local notifications still requires a developer account when testing on a device. Is this correct?

Comment: Yaah. It's correct. I never represented device or simulator in my answer. Any app if you want to be in device whether it's configured with local notification or not you want a developer account

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava,  I am using work manager for background process in flutter which hit the api and once I get response I am showing local notification, I am not using any Firebase FCM Service , so do I need to Choose Push Notification Service while creating identifiers and do I need to use APN SSL certification?

Answer (score 0):

local notification doesn't requires you to have developer account to test somethign on simulator. 
However, you still need developer account if you want this feature to test on actual device.